# Deleting fact in MyHeritage "New Fact" panel?

Tags: myheritage.com

How can I delete a fact that is listed in the "New Fact" panel?

Right now I have a list of 18 "BAPTISM" facts in the right hand pane from which to choose from.

Can I somehow delete 17 of them?

Comment: I answered, but I am unsure of what the "New Fact" panel is that you are referring to. If you could add a screenshot of it to your question (blurring out private info), that would make it obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably delete it from the All facts view of the person:

[image]

To delete a fact, click on the small "x" on the right of the blue header line for the fact:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also delete facts by selecting the person in the tree view which brings up the summary for the person on the left pane:

[image]

You'll see all the facts listed in the left pane. In the above example there are 23 of them.

When your mouse hovers over one of the facts, you'll see an edit icon.

[image]

Click on that and it will bring up a fact box with a trash icon in the bottom left. Click on the trash icon to delete the fact.

[image]

This way, you have to delete them one at a time, but you don't have to bring up the All facts view.